# Wordpress custom supports for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm just using `register_post_type` to generate my new post type 'gcg_block' and generate the ui menu in the admin page. Using `add_post_type_support` for 'author' gives me the column Author in my page (although not sortable). I want to add a column 'Shortcode' to this list and fill it with custom data. I believe I want to create a new support and register it with my post type but I'm unable to find where I could. Am I on the right track or should I be looking at taxonomies for this?

What I'm trying to make is similar to Contact Form 7 list where it displays the shortcode that can be copied to areas in wordpress.

```
add_action( 'init', 'GCG_init' );
// 
function GCG_init() {

  //Register custom post type and create menu
  register_post_type( 'gcg_block', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Generic Content',
        'singular_name' => 'Block' ),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    //'supports' => array( 
    //  'title',
    //  'author',
    //  'editor',)
  ));

  add_post_type_support( 'gcg_block', 'author' );
}
```

Comment: please post any code that you've tried to solve this problem. it's too difficult to tell where you currently are in the solution

Comment: Wordpress has a specific meaning for 'Shortcode'. What expectation do you this shortcode column on your CPT?

Comment: Updated the op.

Comment: Do you have a custom field that generates or stores the shortcode for that post?  You need a field with that data before you can display it.

Comment: I do not, how would I register a custom field? Would it be with update_post_meta?

Answer (score 0):

So I was on the wrong track. I'm using [this blog post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types) about adding new columns to a custom post type and [this example](https://generatewp.com/the-meta-box-generator/) metabox generator to edit the metadata. I did not need to create a custom support. Thanks everyone for your help!